# Objects are not valid as a React child - React Hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I'm trying to get all items from a rest endpoint. But Unfortunately, I get an error. Can somebody please look at my code and tell me where I'm going wrong. This is the JSON data. I'm using React Hooks. And fetching data from a local rest endpoint to get project details.

```
    const [data, setData] = useState();
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
    const [isError, setIsError] = useState(false);


    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
            setIsError(false);
            setIsLoading(true);

            try {
                const result = await axios('http://192.168.0.176:8080/projectses');

                setData(result.data);
            } catch (error) {
                setIsError(true);
            }

            setIsLoading(false);
        };

        fetchData();
    }, []);

const { colors } = useTheme();
const theme = useTheme();

return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
        
      <Text>{data}</Text>

      </View>
   
);



  "project_ID" : 2,

  "project_NAME" : "Project B",

  "_links" : {

    "self" : {

      "href" : "http://192.168.0.176:8080/projectses/2"

    },

    "projects" : {

      "href" : "http://192.168.0.176:8080/projectses/2"

    }

  }
```

Comment: What should `<Text>` display? If `data` is an object what should appear on the screen? Either map `data` to a React component or just display text.

Answer (score 0):

That's true, you probably need to do something like this.

```js
return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <Text>{data.project_ID}</Text>
    <Text>{data.project_NAME}</Text>
  </View>
)
```

Also add some guards before this.

```js
if (!data) return <Text>No data!</Text>;
if (isError) return <Text>Something went wrong!</Text>;
```

Comment: Hi, how do I handle the data if the response was an array?

Comment: You can `.map` through them, e.g.: `{data.map((project) => <Text>{project.project_ID}</Text>}`.

Comment: I get an error, undefined is not a function near ...data.map...

Comment: `const [data, setData] = useState()` you need to pass an empty array here when you initialize your data, ` useState([])`. If your response is an array of course.

Comment: I'm sorry but I tried that before and still I got the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I think if data is array you can you map like this:

```
return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    {
      data.map((item) => <Text>{item.project_ID}</Text>)
    }
  </View>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

`<Text>{data}</Text>` data here is Text's child, and you cant add plain object as child to a function component.

since your endpoint should fetcht an array of items you should initialize your data as an empty array `const [data, setData] = useState([]);` and at view you can map through. if you initialize as null you will get an error since at initial mount you will call map function on null, and null doesnt have map function.

now you can iterate your array. you should give an unique key identifier for each one.

```
{
  data.map(project => <Text key={project.project_ID}>{project.project_NAME}</Text>)
}
```

if you start your data state as null or undefined you need to do a validation prior:

```
{
  data && data.map(project => <Text key={project.project_ID}>{project.project_NAME}</Text>)
}
```

`&&` will only evaluate the second part if data evaluates to true. this is a common practice, specially when you have async calls without an initial state.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I did exactly this and yet I get the same error. TypeError: Undefined is not a function type near ...data.map...

Comment: if you set `useState([])` and still face this error, then when you update your state on async call you are updating to undefined. you should check the result.data